# Tire and size recommendation

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, compatibility, size

I'm resurrecting my 1995 Mongoose IBOC Zero G bike after several years in storage.  I need to replace the tires and tubes.  I will be riding almost exclusively on paved or groomed trails so I don't need mountain bike tires.

Current: Panaracer Dart and Smoke 26x2.10 on Araya TM-18 rims

I am hoping for some expert guidance on a recommendation for what tires and what size I should purchase for a safe alternative to the old MTB tires.

Answer (score 0):

Something with a street tread would better suit your situation.

TM-18 is an 18 mm inside rim width so according to the chart linked in the comment above you can fit a 1 inch to a 1.95 inch tire.

You are at 2.10 inch now - larger than the chart recommends but it's working.

Wider tires generally allow lower tire pressure that tends to be more comfortable but heavier.
Narrower tires generally require higher tire pressures that ride harder and are usually lighter.

So it depends on how you want your bike to ride.
There are many good tires to choose from.
Product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: Thank you David D.  Your answer helps very much.  I am in the process of working my way through learning what I can from the canonical information.  I will continue learning from the canonical answer with the info you have given me.